# Listen to webhook with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks

I am trying to listen to a third-app webhook with Laravel without success.

This is what I've tried so far :

In my route file :

```
Route::post('https://xxxx/webhook/inspector','webappAdmin\WebhookController@inspector');
```

(I've added the route in an except array in the VerifyCSRFtoken middleware)

An exception should be thrown by my controller but nothing happens..

Can anyone help me with a PHP library to listen to webhook ? I've tried the spatie client library but it's not working for me..

Thanks for your help.

Louis